How to split a string using a regex in Powershell?
I want to reformat a string such as pcst400801 to have a hyphen before the last 4 digits: pcst40-0801. I've tried using -split and .Split() with no success. They both provide different results. -split seems to be closest but neither method provides me with something I can do anything with.
.Split():
> $string = "pcst400801"
> $string.Split("(?=\D{4}\d{2})")
pcst400801

-split:
> $string = "pcst400801"
> $string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})"          

pcst40
0801
> $s1,$s2 = $string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})"
> $s1

> $s2
pcst40
0801

In the -split example, it sets $s1 to null and sets $s2 to both of the substrings at the point I want them split. I then tried to split $s2 using \n as the delimiter but got an error about calling a method on a null-valued expression.
I also tried $s1,$s2 = $string -split "(?=\D{4}\d{2})" which gave the same result as not using ?=. $s1 was still null but $s2 was the entire string.
How do I split the string at the point I want and assign each substring to a variable?

Have you seen this question? If you have then why did it not help you?

What about Substring rather than -split, i.e. "pcst400801".Substring(0,6) + "-" + "pcst400801".Substring(6)


To complement the existing, helpful answers (especially iRon's detailed explanation):
Since your intent is to insert a character (or substring) into an existing string,[1] -replace, the regular-expression-based string replacement operator, is a natural choice:
# Insert a "-" before the last 4 digits (\d) at the end ($)
'pcst400801' -replace '\d{4}$', '-$&'

# Alternative, using your original approach:
# Insert a "-" after 4 non-digits (\D) followed by 2 digits (\d) at the start (^)
'pcst400801' -replace '^\D{4}\d{2}', '$&-'

Both expressions return the desired string, 'pcst40-0801'
Note:

$& is a placeholder representing whatever the regex matched in full; see Substitutions in regular expressions for a complete list of all placeholders.

Even though these placeholders resemble PowerShell variable references, due to starting with $, they are unrelated to PowerShell and instead interpreted by the .NET regex engine.
To avoid confusion, it is therefore advisable to use verbatim strings (single-quoted, i.e. '...'), as used above, when specifying regexes or substitution expressions, unless PowerShell-side string interpolation is truly needed (and even then there are alternatives to using expandable (interpolating) strings (double-quoted, i.e. "...")).




[1] Loosely speaking; technically, it is a new string that must be created with the desired insertion, given that .NET strings (System.String, [string] in PowerShell terms) are immutable.

Explanation of what you tried
First of all the major difference between the String.Split() method and the -Split operator is that the operator supports a regular expression and the method not.
Both functions split on a a delimiter string where the delimiter itself is in fact flushed.
$String.Split('40')
pcst
0801

For the split method, if you use a zero-length delimiter ($String.Split('')), it will return nothing, meaning that it is unlikely that you will be able to use this method for your issue.
For the split operator however, you might use a "subexpression" ("(...)") in the form of a Lookahead or Lookbehind ((?=\D{4}\d{2}) as in your split() method attempt) or a simple regular expression capturing group ((\D{4}\d{2}) as in your -split operator attempt) to exclude that part from the delimiter that is usually flushed.
The point is that the regular expression will return multiple results (split) by itself including the main expression result and any additional subexpressions results.
Meaning, the result of the regex you trying to implement contains two values:
[Regex]::Match($string, "(\D{4}\d{2})").Groups | Select-Object Name, Length, Value

Name Length Value
---- ------ -----
0         6 pcst40
1         6 pcst40

Definition (quote from regular-expressions.info):

Parentheses Create Numbered Capturing Groups
Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses also create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the parentheses.
The regex Set(Value)? matches Set or SetValue. In the first case, the first (and only) capturing group remains empty. In the second case, the first capturing group matches Value.
Non-Capturing Groups
If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize this regular expression into Set(?:Value)?. The question mark and the colon after the opening parenthesis are the syntax that creates a non-capturing group.

As far as I can determine, it isn't possible to define regular expression that results in a single zero-length string. Even using a question mark and the colon (?:...) as for the non-capturing group will always be a subset of one or more groups which can't be smaller than a zero-length string.
Solutions and alternatives

You might simply void everything before the main (split) expression (which is also a zero length string) with an assign to $null as in the helpful answer from vht981230:

$null,$s1,$s2 = $string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})"


Specify the items you need from the array:
(Note that you might also use negative numbers for the indices)

$s1,$s2 = ($string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})")[1,2]
$s1,$s2 = ($string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})")[-2,-1]


Use a negative <Max-substrings> number (PowerShell 7+, see: #4765, #24650):


$string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})", -2



Use a lookbehind (?<=..)..:

$s1,$s2 = $string -split "(?<=\D{4}\d{2})"


You might be more specific here to exclude strings that do not match at all (e.g. $string = "pcst1234567890abcdef"

$s1,$s2 = $string -split "^(?<=\D{4}\d{2})(?=\d{4})$"


or even specify the start and end of the start (using ^ and $):

$s1,$s2 = $string -split "(?<=^\D{4}\d{2})(?=\d{4}$)" 


In general, from the quoted definition and from a common script design, I would discourage you from using the -split operator for this (especially where you try to define anything but the delimiter) and use the -match operator with the automatic $Matches variable instead. This will allow for a better way of checking whether the $string matches the pattern which likely has to be done anyways to prevent unexpected outcomes or the use of ugly Try/Catch blocks:

if ($string -match "(^\D{4}\d{2})(\d{4}$)") { $s1,$s2 = $Matches[1,2] }
else { Write-Error "'$string' doesn't match the pattern." }


For your specific use case (which I completely overlooked), it wil probably make even more sense to go the -replace operator as mklement pointed out in his helpful answer.


@mklement0, thanks for your feedback, I will investigate it later today and update the answer accordingly.

@mklement0 , I have updated the answer. Thanks again, I learned two new things about PowerShell and regexes today from your comment ((?:...)) and answer (($&).

I think you're pretty close on the -spit approach, you just need to have an additional null variable at the beginning to avoid the empty string being assigned to $s1
$null,$s1,$s2 = $string -split "(\D{4}\d{2})"


Nice, but it's not a newline that is returned as the first element, is the empty string that constitutes the first token, due to the separator regex matching at the very start of the input string.

@mklement0 Oh I see, thank you for clarifying

Doing it with some array indexing:
$string = 'pcst400801'
-join ($string[-($string.length)..-5] + '-' + $string[-4..-1])

pcst40-0801


This is a bit obscure and also inefficient. If you want a solution based on statically extracted _substrings, use $pos = $string.Length-4; $string.Substring(0, $pos) + '-' + $string.Substring($pos)
